# How to use custom Input with Formik in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, formik

I'm trying to use [DatePicker](https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/) within [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/). But when I click DatePicker's date its form value is not changed. Instead, I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.persist is not a function
>   at Formik._this.handleChange (formik.es6.js:5960)

I shortify code, the code is below

```
const SomeComponent = () => (
    <Formik
        render={({
            values,
            handleSubmit,
            handleChange,
            setFieldValue
        }) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <DatePicker
                            name={'joinedAt'}
                            value={values['joinedAt']}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }}
    />
)
```

I googled few documents, https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/187 and https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/86

So I tried like below, but it's not working.

```
 ...setFieldValue

 <DatePicker
   name={'joinedAt'}
   value={values['joinedAt']}
   onChange={setFieldValue}
 />
```

Comment: I guess you need to use your own `handleChange` method or adapt the existing

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I resolve this like

```
<DatePicker
   name={'joinedAt'}
   value={values['joinedAt']}
   onChange={e => setFieldValue('joinedAt', e)}
/>
```

**Update on 2020-03-08:**

You can use `e.target.value` on setFieldValue's second prop, depends on your custom input design. Thanks to Brandon.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't recognise the date selected

Comment: `onChange={e => setFieldValue('joinedAt', e.target.value)}`

Answer (score 14):

If you have deeper nesting, you should use Formik [Field](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field). 
Example:

```js
<Formik
    validationSchema={schema}
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {}}
>

  <Field name="colors" component={ColorsEditor}  colors={colorArray}/>
</Formik>


const ColorsEditor = ({ field, colors, form, ...props }) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={() => form.setFieldValue('colors', "myValue")}>
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So the Field component already include the form, where live the setFieldValue that you can use where you need. It also include the errors and needed fields for additional customization.

Answer (score 3):

For html primitive input fields handleChange works like a charm, but for custom components, you've to use `setFieldValue` to change the value imperatively.

```
onChange={e => setFieldValue('joinedAt', e)}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me and didn't show the selected date. It has been almost a year so there might be some changes with the implementation. Though this can be fix by using  `toDateString()` like this

```
<DatePicker
   name={'joinedAt'}
   value={values['joinedAt']}
   onChange={e => setFieldValue('joinedAt', e.toDateString())}
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

The Formik solution for this is the `useField()` method. You may need to create a wrapper for components like DatePicker that you may not have source access to.

The [documentation](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField) provides an example:

```js
const MyTextField = ({ label, ...props }) => {
   const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props);
   return (
     <>
       <label>
         {label}
         <input {...field} {...props} />
       </label>
       {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
         <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
       ) : null}
     </>
   );
 };
```

In short, the method takes in the custom props which describe the field. Then you can expand the assigned field value and props in your custom field.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/692

you need to set value manually if you are using setFieldValue method

Comment: He is using setFieldValue from props