# Custom change handlers with inputs inside Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm porting some of my forms I made using [SUIR](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) over to a [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik) implementation. I have input components that need custom change handlers to perform actions. How can I pass my change handler to the `onChange` prop so the values are tracked by formik?

I've tried something like this, but with no luck.

```
onChange={e => setFieldValue(dataSchemaName, e)}
```

which is mentioned in a different post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271766/how-to-use-custom-input-with-formik-in-react).

It's also mentioned [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1243#issuecomment-461176174), but I can't quite get my custom change handler to hook up nicely with Formik.

My change handler looks like this

```
handleSchemaChange = (e, { value }) => {
  this.setState({ dataSchemaName: value }, () => {
     console.log("Chosen dataSchema ---> ", this.state.dataSchemaName);
     //also send a request the selfUri of the selected dataSchema
  });
  const schema = this.state.dataschemas.find(schema => schema.name === value);
if (schema) {
  axios
    .get(schema.selfUri)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({
        fields: response.data.data.fields,
      });
      console.log(this.state.fields);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
  }
};
```

Here's an example of one of my form fields using a dropdown

```
<Form.Field>
  <label style={{ display: "block" }}>
    Select a Schema
  </label>
  <Dropdown
    id="dataSchemaName"
    multiple={false}
    options={dataschemas.map(schema => {
      return {
        key: schema.id,
        text: schema.name,
        value: schema.name
      };
    })}
    value={dataSchemaName}
    onChange={this.handleSchemaChange}
  />
</Form.Field>
```

I have a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-create-query-schema-z55f0) with the issue

Comment: So you want to take some action when a specific input changes, right?

Comment: I just want to use the change handlers as I would with normal form input components

Comment: You can not do that via formik. Better you don t use formik.

Comment: I"m not convinced that's entirely true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass the `setFieldValue` function to your function `handleSchemaChange` and then use it inside.

So, instead of `onChange={this.handleSchemaChange}` make it 
`onChange={(e, val) => this.handleSchemaChange(e, val, setFieldValue)}`.

And inside your `handleSchemaChange` function:

```
handleSchemaChange = (e, { value }, setFieldValue) => {
    setFieldValue('dataSchemaName', value);
    ... the rest of your implementation
}
```

Here is a sandbox with the solution implemented:
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-create-query-schema-uq35f

Comment: Thanks much, Is this in the docs somewhere that would could link?

Comment: Other than this https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void , I don't believe so.

The solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271766/how-to-use-custom-input-with-formik-in-react was correct but in your case it needed this tweak `onChange={(e, val) => setFieldValue('dataSchemaName', val.value)}` since the first argument was the event object and the second was the object returned from the Semantic-UI Dropdown component which contained the value you needed to set.