# In React with Formik how can I build a search bar that will detect input value to render the buttons?

Tags: reactjs, user-input, formik

New to Formik and React I've built a search component that I'm having issues with the passing of the input value and rendering the buttons based on input length.

Given the component:

```js
const SearchForm = ({ index, store }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true)

  const [query, setQuery] = useState(null)
  const results = useLunr(query, index, store)
  const renderResult = results.length > 0 || query !== null ? true : false

  useEffect(() => {
    if (input.length >= 3) setDisable(false)
    console.log('input detected', input)
  }, [input])

  const onReset = e => {
    setInput('')
    setDisable(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ query: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          setInput('')
          setDisable(true)

          setQuery(values.query)
          setSubmitting(false)
        }}
      >
        <Form className="mb-5">
          <div className="form-group has-feedback has-clear">
            <Field
              className="form-control"
              name="query"
              placeholder="Search . . . . ."
              onChange={e => setInput(e.currentTarget.value)}
              value={input}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <div className="text-right">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mr-1" disabled={disable}>
                  Submit
                </button>
                <button
                  type="reset"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  value="Reset"
                  disabled={disable}
                  onClick={onReset}
                >
                  <IoClose />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </Formik>

      {renderResult && <SearchResults query={query} posts={results} />}
    </>
  )
}
```

I've isolated where my issue is but having difficulty trying to resolve:

```js
<Field
  className="form-control"
  name="query"
  placeholder="Search . . . . ."
  onChange={e => setInput(e.currentTarget.value)}
  value={input}
/>
```

From within the Field's `onChange` and `value` are my problem. If I have everything as posted on `submit` the passed query doesn't exist. If I remove both and hard code a `true` for the submit button my query works.

### Research

- [Custom change handlers with inputs inside Formik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570074/custom-change-handlers-with-inputs-inside-formik)
- [Issue with values Formik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613496/issue-with-values-formik)
- [Why is OnChange not working when used in Formik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013702/why-is-onchange-not-working-when-used-in-formik)

In Formik how can I build a search bar that will detect input value to render the buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tap into the props that are available as part of the `Formik` component.  Their docs show a [simple example](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#example) that is similar to what you'll need:

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={{ query: '' }}
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setInput('')
    otherStuff()
  }}
>
  {formikProps => (
    <Form className="mb-5">
      <div className="form-group has-feedback has-clear">
        <Field
          name="query"
          onChange={formikProps.handleChange}
          value={formikProps.values.query}
        />
      </div>
      <button 
        type="submit" 
        disabled={!formikProps.values.query}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
      <button
        type="reset"
        disabled={!formikProps.values.query}
        onClick={formikProps.resetForm}
      >
    </Form>
    {/* ... more stuff ... */}
  )}
</Formik>
```

[image: Working Codesandbox]

You use this render props pattern to pull formiks props out (I usually call them `formikProps`, but you can call them anything you want), which then has access to everything you need.  Rather than having your `input`, `setInput`, `disable`, and `setDisable` variables, you can just reference what is in your formikProps.  For example, if you want to disable the submit button, you can just say `disable={!formikProps.values.query}`, meaning if the `query` value in the form is an empty string, you can't submit the form.

As far as `onChange`, as long as you give a field the correct `name` as it corresponds to the property in your `initialValues` object, `formikProps.handleChange` will know how to properly update that value for you.  Use `formikProps.values.whatever` for the `value` of the field, an your component will read those updates automatically.  The combo of `name`, `value`, and `onChange`, all handled through formikProps, makes form handing easy.

Formik has tons of very useful prebuilt functionality to handle this for you.  I recommend hanging out on their docs site and you'll see how little of your own code you have to write to handle these common form behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for that I see now where I was going wrong. +1 also for the excellent answer.

Comment: Can’t tell you how much this answer has helped me +100 as far as I’m concerned 

Comment: @Richlewis always welcome to bounty the question and award the bounty.

Comment: How do I bounty the question when I didn’t raise it?

Comment: anyone can bounty a question per memory. Under the actual question there is the link `Start a bounty` you can click on it and assign 100. After the allotted time you can reward it to Seth.

Comment: @Richlewis wow I don't even remember writing this answer, I'm glad it helped. I will gladly accept free meaningless internet points from a retroactive bounty if you feel so moved 

Comment: Will award in 23 hours :-) (that's what SO is saying)... I may have another question of my own soon, so maybe you can earn some more meaningless internet points :-)

Comment: And for context, i've been banging my head against a brick wall trying to create a search feature using a flatlist with a formik form.. this answer definitely helped move a few bricks

Comment: @Richlewis feel free to post the question and link me, and it, in a comment here, so I can find it.  I work with formik alot (way too much!), and I do some stuff with react-native as well so I'm familiar with flatlists and the like

Comment: @SethLutske if you have some time please could you take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144415/update-input-field-with-clicked-flatlist-item-formik I hope theres enough info around my issue, if not though please let me know if i need to update the question/code with further detail, thank you.. Im also not sure about the way im passing `formikProps` to my child component, you should see what i mean

Comment: @SethLutske it's ok, i've figured it out :-) whether its the right way im not sure, but for now it's working